# Where does the NetBeans NbPreferences API store its config file?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, config, archlinux

I use the NetBeans NbPreferences to store preferences for my NetBeans plugin like so:

```
static Preferences prefsStorage;
prefsStorage = NbPreferences.forModule(LLPreferences.class);
for (int i = 0; i < keyCount; i++){
        prefsStorage.put(keys.get(i).toString(), values.get(i).toString());
        System.out.println("Prefs to store: " + prefsStorage.get(keys.get(i).toString(), ""));
}
prefsStorage.flush();
```

At least that is an extract of some code just to give you the idea. Now the problem is that I need to do some debugging work with the program and it would be highly useful if I could actually view the actual config file in a text editor on disk to see what is actually there between runs. However, even though so documentation suggests it to be in `~/.netbeans`, I cannot find it anywhere and I'm really not too sure of where to look. It's not in the `etc` folder either of my NetBeans installation directory.

So where would this file be being stored if it actually real?

I have Java 8 with NetBeans 8.2 and the latest of Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The preferences are not stored within the NetBeans installation directory. They are stored in a properties file within the NetBeans project, where the name of the that file is the project file name in lower case. For example, for project **MyProject** the settings are stored in **myproject.properties**.

A good NetBeans tutorial on this, which only takes a few minutes, can be found here:

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-options.html

I ran that tutorial using Java 8 and NetBeans 8.2, and it worked fine, creating a preferences file named **cooloptions.properties** under the following folder structure:

[image: preferences file]

In my case the full path of the properties file containing the preferences for the tutorial was:

*D:/NetBeansProjects/CoolOptions/build/testuserdir/**config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/cooloptions.properties***

The final part of that path should also be valid for your preferences file as well:

*blah...blah....**/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/{project name}.properties***

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**Update:**
The previous test was run on Windows 10. I repeated the test on Linux Mint 18.2 using Java 8 (u144) and NetBeans 8.2, and the result was the same: the preferences were persisted in a properties file as detailed above. A shot of the project's file structure on Linux is shown below.

The **store()** method used for persisting the preferences (heavily based on the tutorial cited above) looked like this:

```
static Preferences prefsStorage;

void store() {
    try {
        prefsStorage = NbPreferences.forModule(CoolPanel.class);
        prefsStorage.put("namePreference", jTextField1.getText());
        prefsStorage.flush();
        String absPath = prefsStorage.absolutePath();
        System.out.println("absPath=" + absPath);
    } catch(BackingStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Since your code is working fine the brute force approach to find out where your preference are being stored is to enter some distinctive value for one of your preferences, and then use **grep** to locate the file that stores it.

And if that doesn't work I can only suggest running the tutorial I linked to above that persists preferences in a **NetBeans Module** using **NbPreferences**. It only takes a few minutes, and it will either work or fail, but either way you  may get some further insight into your problem.

[image: Linux Mint File structure]

Comment: Can you please try to specifically create a NetBeans Module  which you will find in the category list if you try to create a new project. This is a plugin and I believe at least has a different structure to what you are showing as I can't find it under there.

Comment: And it should be the properties file specifically created using the NbPreferences API that I gave an example of in my question.

Comment: @Paranoid Panda The project I created was a NetBeans Module that used the NbPreferences API. I updated my post above after repeating the test on Linux, showing the code used to persist the preference.